# How to create an automatic JavaFX Media Player

Tags: javafx

I have developed my own media player in JavaFX. I have converted it to .exe format using Launch4J. But I want to program it in such a way that on selecting an .mp3 file, the OS should automatically play the file in my java media player program converted to exe format.

Comment: You can do this manually; just look up how to associate files with an application for your platform. I couldn't find how to do this automatically with Launch4J though. If you're using Java 14, however, then you could try `jpackage` (currently incubating) which has [an option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html#options-for-creating-the-application-package) (`--file-associations`) to configure associated files.

Comment: Keep in mind you have to code your application for this functionality. I believe that simply entails checking the command line arguments for any file paths and doing whatever you need to with them. For JavaFX, see [`Application#getParameters()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters()).